# How to build legends for the ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How I can add legend to the plot based on the following code where the `blue` line would be called as `observation` and the `red` line as `simulation`?

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), to = as.Date("2001-12-31"), by = "day"),
                 Calib = runif(365,5,10), Valid = runif(365,2,8))

ggplot(DF, aes(x = Date))+
  geom_line(aes(y = Calib), col = "blue")+
  geom_line(aes(y = Valid), col = "red")
```

Comment: I would say most often the easiest thing to do is to reshape your data into long format so you can color by the group of interest.  If you want to build manual legends, though, you can, by moving `color` inside `aes()`.  I wrote a post about this [here](https://aosmith.rbind.io/2018/07/19/manual-legends-ggplot2/), which may help if you are looking to do manual legends.

Comment: Thanks for sharing link to the blog- this is really helpful. I was looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

as @aosmith stated best to reshape these data something, like this would do it

```
data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), to = as.Date("2001-12-31"), by = "day"),
           Calib = runif(365,5,10), Valid = runif(365,2,8)) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-Date) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Date, value, color = name)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Item",
                     values = c("blue", "red"))
```